# Is there a way to add !important to multiple css values with scss?

Tags: css, sass

Let's say I had a few classes that I needed to be able to add `!important` to the values in the class. Is there an efficient way of doing that? I'm still learning scss so I'm really sorry if this has been asked, I just haven't been able to find the answer.

**Update**

I did find that I could create a variable and add it to the end of every value like this:

```
$i: !important;
$button-background-color: #03A9F4;
$button-color: #fff;

.button {
  border-radius:2px$i;
  color: $button-color$i;
  background-color: $button-background-color$i;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s$i;
  transition:all .3s$i;
  border:0px$i;
  padding:0px$i;
  &:hover {
    background-color: lighten( $button-background-color, 20% )$i;
  }
  &.primary {
    height: 40px$i;
  }
  &.secondary {
    height: 30px$i;
    padding:0 10px$i;
  }
}
```

Is that the fastest way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach with scss is to double up the specificity. You could do something like this:

```
.parent.parent {}
```

Everything within will have higher specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when css file is structured well you will not use !important so often, except in cases when you need to override some behaviors dynamically. Is css rules are written from top to bottom and last one has priority. Also watch on order how you import your scss files.
Another thing to mention so avoid using !important is specificity. Inline elements take highest specificity, then id, then classes and then elements itself. If you look carefully on all this rules you should end up with using !important very rare.

Comment: Okay but it's not optional in my situation so I need to know if it's possible, not whether it's good to use.

Comment: I don't know if there fast solution for this in css/sass. Your approach seems fine if that is what you need. As for dynamically added !important maybe you can checkout [this](https://www.html5andbeyond.com/jquery-add-important-css-properties-dynamically/) article and use it in your code.

Answer (score -3):

`!important` isn't right way, It can be manage by add its parent class in css like, `.footer .content`  or change css file position if more than one css file, high priority css file must be bottom than lower priority level css file.

Comment: It may not be the best practice but it exists for a reason. Either way this is not an answer.